# Coefficent alteration of the elliptic curve equation in Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Something caught my attention while reading about the mathematics behind Elliptic Curve Cryptography.

When setting up the elliptic curve equation for communicating between parties, why are only the $a$ and $b$ variables altered, whereas the coefficients of $y^2$ and $x^3$ are kept constant at 1? Is there a specific reason behind or is it just standard?

Here is the general elliptic curve equation just in case: $y^2=x^3+ax+b$.

Comment: Understood, however, I am just asking why is $y^2$  and $x^3$ kept constant at 1 whereas the other variables are changed?. Is it just because of the rules or can we also use a Weierstrass curve for ECC with the equation $2y^2 = 5x^3 -2x +4$ for example?

Comment: Okay, thanks. But for the case of the example equation I just wrote, the curve still seems to be symmetric on the [$x-axis$](https://ibb.co/m0wp396). Is that still not valid to be used in ECC?

Comment: Up to an "easy bijection" the equation in characteristic $\ne 2,3$ the general form is: $$y^2=x^3+a_4x+a_6\ .$$The "general form" is:$$y^2 + a_1xy + a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6\ .$$The (non-zero) coefficients of $y^2$, $x^3$ can always be taken w.l.o.g. to be one. If some coefficients of $y^2$ is there, divide by it to get the coefficient of $y^2$ to be $1$. If now we have an equation of the shape $y^2 +\dots=Sx^3+\dots$, then multiply with $S^2$ and regroup, getting something like $(Sy)^2 + \dots = (Sx)^3+\dots$, then consider this equation as an equation in the new variables $X=Sx$ and $Y=Sy$.